# Sumifs in Excel with date calculations

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

Hi I have data that looks like the following

```
PROVIDER |   DATE     | CLIENT | DURATION
JOHN     | 1/1/2020   | CAT 1  | 50
JOHN     | 11/14/2020 | CAT 2  | 200
JOHN     | 11/8/2020  | CAT 1  | 100
JOHN     | 11/1/2020  | CAT 1  | 150
```

I'm trying to find all of the data that was inputted in by providers within the previous week block. As I write this its 11/18/2020 and the formula I have is...

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$D:$D, 'Sheet1!'$A:$A, "JOHN", 'Sheet1'!$C:$C, ">=" & (NOW()-MOD(NOW()-1, 7)-7))
```

Essentially saying that I want excel to use the sumifs function to find sum the duration values of all rows in sheet 1 where the date value is greater than or equal to 7 days prior to the sunday of the current week.

The only problem is that excel throws an error. It's able to see the range, and is able to correctly find the date of the sunday, but it's not making the comparison within the sumifs function (it seems). Excel isn't letting me turn this into an array formula, so I'm wondering what the issue is.....

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: a #value! error

Comment: there is a typo here: `'Sheet1!'$A:$A`  the `!` is on the wrong side of the `'`

Comment: ok I fixed that. Another issue is that the date value is a text type. Trying to figure out how to convert it to a date......by the way, you've helped me out before on stack overflow scott, a while ago. I can't believe you're still helping people out here.

Comment: There are many examples on how to do that, but the quickest is to use Text to Columns which will do the conversion in mass.